# Is there a more efficient way to run my PHP IF...ELSEIF statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

This is a snippet I just added to my shopping cart that basically renders a select box with 4 choices for quantity and refreshes the page. Originally, there was a simple input box that users could use to manipulate quantities but a small cluster of users weren't actually hitting "Update Cart" before they proceeded to Checkout so I decided to be more proactive. UX practices and AJAX methods aside, I'm just curious if the redundancy of these options is necessary in PHP. How could I make it more efficient?

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="return updateCart();">
<?php if($this->getQty() == 1) : ?>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
<?php elseif($this->getQty() == 2) : ?>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
<?php elseif($this->getQty() == 3) : ?>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
<?php elseif($this->getQty() == 4) : ?>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
<?php else : ?>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
<?php endif; ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Since you have values why not switch to switch. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$quantity = $this->getQty();
for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++){
  if($quantity == $i)
     echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">'.$i.'</option>';
  else
     echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, only call the `getQty()` function once. Save the return value and then check that.

Second, no need for repeating all of the options. Depending on what the actual use-case is, it may make more sense to use a loop, or to do it like this…

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="return updateCart();">
<?php $qty = $this->getQty(); ?>
    <option value="1" <?php if($qty == 1): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if($qty == 2): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if($qty == 3): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>3</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if($qty == 4): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>4</option>
</select>
```

**Example using a loop**

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="return updateCart();">
<?php $qty = $this->getQty();
    for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++):
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($qty == $i): ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="return updateCart();">
    <option value="1" <? echo ($this->getQty()==1?'selected="selected"':""); ?> >1</option>
    <option value="2" <? echo ($this->getQty()==2?'selected="selected"':""); ?> >2</option>
    <option value="3" <? echo ($this->getQty()==3?'selected="selected"':""); ?> >3</option>
    <option value="4" <? echo ($this->getQty()==4?'selected="selected"':""); ?> >4</option>
</select>
```

it wont make your code faster but *smaller* and more *clear*.

In case your options are getting many, consider a for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more condensed, but I don't think its more efficient or better, but you might like it.

```
<select name="quantity" onchange="return updateCart();">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<5;$i++): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php echo ( $this->getQty() == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ); ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```